# How to add another sets of data to the BubbleChart3D without impacting the shape of bubbles?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, output-formatting, charts, plot-themes

I have some codes as below:-

**Data points**

```
k = 9;
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[123]; pts0a = RandomReal[10, {k, 4}];]
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[246]; pts0b = RandomReal[10, {k, 4}];]

pts1a = pts0a;
pts1a[[All, 1]] = pts0a[[All, 1]] - 50;
pts1a[[All, 2]] = pts0a[[All, 2]] + 80;
pts1a[[All, 3]] = pts0a[[All, 3]] + 200;

pts1b = pts0b;
pts1b[[All, 1]] = pts0b[[All, 1]] - 50;
pts1b[[All, 2]] = pts0b[[All, 2]] + 70;
pts1b[[All, 3]] = pts0b[[All, 3]] + 100;

pts1All = {pts1a, pts1b};
```

**Plot settings**

```
boxRatio1 = {0.5, 1.5, 2.7};
plotRange1 = {{-70, -30}, {60, 110}, {0, 250}};
bsizes = {0.1, .5};
```

**Scale functions needed to be modified later**

```
cef2[br_: {1, 1, 1}, pr_: {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, sc_: .1] := 
  Module[{ced = ChartElementData["Bubble3D"][##], 
  rs = sc Rescale[#2[[-1]], #3[[1, 1]], #3[[1, 2]]] Norm[
  Subtract @@ Transpose[pr]] Normalize[-Subtract @@@ pr]/br}, 
  Replace[ced, Scale[a_, b_, c_] :> Scale[a, rs, c], {0, \[Infinity]}]] &;

addMetaData[data_, bsizes_] := Thread[data -> {MinMax[data[[All, -1]]], bsizes}, List, 1];
```

Now, I have some `BubbleChart3D` plots, but they are not what I ultimately want.

**Trial 1**

```
BubbleChart3D[addMetaData[pts1a, bsizes], ImageSize -> 200, 
  BoxRatios -> boxRatio1, PlotRange -> plotRange1, 
  ChartElementFunction -> cef2[boxRatio1, plotRange1]]
```

Trial 1 looks good (e.g. which keep the shape of data as spheres and use the data's 4th column as point sizes). But I want `pts1All` to be plotted in 2 colors, instead of just plotting `pts1a`.

[image]

**Trial 2**

```
BubbleChart3D[pts1All, ImageSize -> 200, BoxRatios -> boxRatio1, PlotRange -> plotRange1]
```

Trial 2 includes both sets of data points in 2 colors, but the shape is not spherical.

[image]

**Trial 3**

```
BubbleChart3D[addMetaData[pts1All, bsizes], ImageSize -> 200,
  BoxRatios -> boxRatio1, PlotRange -> plotRange1,
  ChartElementFunction -> cef2[boxRatio1, plotRange1]]
```

Trial 3 includes both sets of data points in 2 colors, but the size of points are not varying according to the data's 4th column.

[image]

What I want is a plot which fulfills all 3 conditions:-

1. Keep the shape of data as spheres;
2. Use the data's 4th column as point sizes;
3. Includes both sets of data points (i.e. `pts1All`) in 2 colors

I trust I need to modify `cef2` and `addMetaData`, but I don't know what to do. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modification of `addMetaData` that works for both single and multiple datasets:

```
ClearAll[addMetaData2]
addMetaData2[data_, bsizes_] := Module[{minmax = If[Length @ Dimensions @ data == 2, 
    MinMax[data[[All, -1]]],  MinMax[data[[All, All, -1]]]]},
   data -> {minmax, bsizes}];

BubbleChart3D[addMetaData2[pts1All, bsizes], ImageSize -> 200, 
 BoxRatios -> boxRatio1, PlotRange -> plotRange1, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cef2[boxRatio1, plotRange1]]
```

[image]